# Best architecture for creating navigation using MVVM & WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation

I`m begginer in WPF and MVVM.
I created new navigation project which has mainMindow that contains frame.
I also created 3 pages and i want by binding commands from mainWindows to my ViewModel which implements the navigation between pages and show them via the frame.

My quastion is:
What is better to do:

Make each page as singleton or create the instances of the pages in my viewmodel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having a look at [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/).
Among other features, it provides a navigation infrastructure that you could utilize in your project.